Problem with definition of tangent vectors as derivations
It is well-known that one can describe tangent vectors to a smooth manifold $M$ as derivations on germs of functions, see this question. However, according to "Riemannsche Geometrie im Großen" by Gromoll, Klingenberg and Meyer, §1.1.3, A(i), there is an infinite-dimensional vector space of $\mathbb R$-linear maps $\partial\colon C^r(M)\to\mathbb R$ satisfying the usual  product rule $$\partial(fg)=\partial f\cdot g(p)+f(p)\cdot\partial g$$
for function germs $f$, $g$ at $p$,
where $p$ is a point on a finite-dimensional $C^r$-manifold $M$ with $1\le r<\infty$. Is there any accessible description of "strange" derivations that do not originate from tangent vectors in the classical sense, that is, either from velocities of $C^r$-curves, or from a coordinate description behaving correctly under coordinate changes?

I do not see how it would be possible since it would yield a "description" of the algebraic dual of some infinite dimensional vector space. Then you get into issues related to the axiom of choice... I am actually unsure if the existence of exotic derivations is independent of the axiom of choice. Maybe logicians here can help with this...

@MoisheKohan I would be surprised if this was a logics problem. The only proof that I know rewrites a $C^k$ function as a sum of products $g_i\cdot x^i$, where the $g_i$ are $C^{k-1}$ functions and the $x^i$ are coordinates. But then $g_i$ is no longer in the domain of the derivation, unless $k=\infty$. So for finite $k$, you cannot apply the product rule anymore.

If you look more closely, then you see how the axiom of choice shows up. In particular, the accepted answer to your question is quite wrong.

Take a look at my answer here where this is spelled out in the case $r=1$. When one says "extend the given linearly independent subset to a basis" one uses AC.

@MoisheKohan You are of course right, the axiom of choice is used here to construct actual derivations. Anyway, the answer below halfway solves my original problem: it explains why there is a rich predual of the space of derivations. For me, that is "accessible" enough, even though a concrete construction of one such thing would have been nicer (it is still not clear that this is impossible).

@OrangeMushroom: The original question asked for a "description" of accesible derivation. Your answer only proves existence; not a single exotic derivation is described. What you described is a linearly independent subset of the dual space of the space of derivations. But, I see that even this is enough to OP, so be it.

@MoisheKohan I sense some sour grapes…

@NateRiver: No, just sense of an unsatisfactory answer. The actual question remains unanswered.

I think there are no "derivations that do not originate from tangent vectors in the classical sense".
Indeed, any derivation $D$ must satisfy the chain rule
$$(Df)(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n(D_i f)(p)(Dx^i)(p)$$
at every point $p\in M$, where $f$ is a smooth enough function on $M$, $x^i$ is the $i$th coordinate function near $p$, and $(D_i f)(p)$ is the partial derivative of $f$ at $p$ wrt the $i$th coordinate. Letting now
$v=(v^1,\dots,v^n)=((Dx^1)(p),\dots,(Dx^n)(p))$, we get
$$(Df)(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n(D_i f)(p)v^i=(D_v f)(p),$$
the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction of $v$.

The only proof of your first formula that I know uses functions similar to $g(x)=\begin{cases}(f(x)-f(0))/x&x\ne0\f'(0)&x=0\end{cases}$ in dimension $1$. But $g$ has one derivative less than $f$, so one cannot apply $D$ to it. But maybe you do this differently?

@SebastianGoette : This is a good point. Let me think about this.
